Graphql Yoga and mongodb build to Heroku
The project stack is made up of nodejs, graphql yoga and mongodb and I am trying to build it to heroku. The build works perfectly locally but the issue though is that on heroku the build is successful but it immediately crashes when I open it up.
Here is the index.js file:
const {execute, ExecutionArgs, subscribe} = require('graphql');
const {makeBehavior} = require('graphql-ws/lib/use/uWebSockets');
const {createSchema, createYoga, Repeater, createPubSub} = require('graphql-yoga');
const {App, HttpRequest, HttpResponse} = require('uWebSockets.js');

const typeDefs = require('./src/schema');
const resolvers = require('./src/resolvers/index');
const models = require('./src/models/index');
const {decode} = require('next-auth/jwt');
const {connect} = require('./src/db');
const {useResponseCache} = require("@graphql-yoga/plugin-response-cache");
const {useDeferStream} = require("@graphql-yoga/plugin-defer-stream");
// Connect to MongoDB
connect(process.env.DB_HOST).then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB!");
    console.log(process.env.PORT, process.env.NODE_ENV)
}).catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
    console.log('MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDB is running.');
    process.exit();
});

const pubSub = createPubSub()

const yoga = createYoga({
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
        methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
        allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
    },
    schema: createSchema({
        typeDefs: typeDefs,
        resolvers: resolvers,
    }),
    plugins: [
        useDeferStream(),

    ],
    context: async ({ request: req}) => {
        let token = req?.headers?.get('authorization')?.split(' ')[1] || (req?.headers?.get("authorization")) 
        // let token = req?.headers?.get('authorization')?.split(' ')[1];
        //check if introspection query
        if (req?.body?.query?.includes("IntrospectionQuery")) {
            return {
                models,
                user: null,
            };
        }
        const start = Date.now();
        try {
            const jwtPayload = await decode({
                token: token,
                secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
            });
            // console.log("jwtPayload", jwtPayload)
            const mid = new Date().getTime();
            const user = await models.User.findOne({email: jwtPayload?.email}, {
                _id: 1,
                email: 1,
                preferences: 1,
                accountType: 1,

            });
            const end = new Date().getTime();
            const duration = end - start;
            // console.log(`Request took: ${duration}ms`, end - mid);
            return {
                pubSub,
                user,
                models,
            };
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            return {
                models,
                user: null,
            };
        }
    },
    graphiql: {
        subscriptionsProtocol: 'WS', // use WebSockets instead of SSE
    },
});

// yoga's envelop may augment the `execute` and `subscribe` operations
// so we need to make sure we always use the freshest instance


const wsHandler = makeBehavior({
    execute: args => (args).rootValue.execute(args),
    subscribe: args => (args).rootValue.subscribe(args),
    onSubscribe: async (ctx, msg) => {
        const {schema, execute, subscribe, contextFactory, parse, validate} = yoga.getEnveloped(ctx);

        const args = {
            schema,
            operationName: msg.payload.operationName,
            document: parse(msg.payload.query),
            variableValues: msg.payload.variables,
            contextValue: await contextFactory(),
            rootValue: {
                execute,
                subscribe,
            },
        };

        const errors = validate(args.schema, args.document);
        if (errors.length) return errors;
        return args;
    },
});

const port = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.PORT : 8080;

console.log('PORT:', process.env.PORT);

App()
    .any('/*', yoga)
    .ws(yoga.graphqlEndpoint, wsHandler)
    .listen(port, (token) => {
        if (token) {
            console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
        } else {
            console.error('Failed to start server');
        }
    });

// Handle graceful shutdown
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
    console.log('SIGTERM signal received. Shutting down gracefully.');
    // Perform any necessary cleanup here
    process.exit(0);
});

// export const app = App().any('/*', yoga).ws(yoga.graphqlEndpoint, wsHandler);

The error showing up in the heroku logs:
2024-06-20T18:51:38.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2024-06-20T18:52:47.676067+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=dev-mole-backend-239ec47a5642.herokuapp.com request_id=c27c796d-5109-401d-8041-9f1e8d3283b6 fwd="108.30.174.209" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

I believe there is some issue with the App() function at the bottom and the port which in the env is set to development locally and production in heroku.

Are you setting the PORT environment variable yourself in the dashboard? If so, remove it and redeploy. Heroku provisions its own process.env.PORT that your app will use.

@8ctopotamus I'm not setting it myself. But good thought.

If you console.log(process.env.PORT) and look at your Heroku Logs (heroku logs --tail) do you see the value coming through or do you see undefined?
If you're not seeing a value come through, you may want to try installing and configuring the dotenv package

@8ctopotamus  I added:
console.log('PORT:', process.env.PORT, "env:", process.env.NODE_ENV, "condition:",process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production');
which returned:
2024-06-20T19:45:09.544330+00:00 app[web.1]: PORT: 6298 env: production condition: true

@8ctopotamus, dotenv is not needed (and shouldn't be used) on Heroku. Environment variables aren't set via files there.

@Chris, Yep, I know that they get set in the dashboard instead. I just usually happen to have dotenv in my code to read the file locally. Good to know that this doesn't make a difference on Heroku!
